# Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$list_data

Tags: php, json, api

I am trying to access data using API and want to show data on HTML table. Many of the time this code run without any problem but sometime it show error 
`Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$list_data
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`

I search for this problem on google but unable to solve this problem because I am beginner at php.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $opts = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST'
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $json = file_get_contents('https://faucethub.io/api/listv1/faucetlist?api_key=API_KEY', false, $context);
    $obj = json_decode($json);
?>

<?php
    $gg = $obj->list_data->premium->BTC;
    if (is_array($gg))
        {
        foreach(array_slice($gg, 0, 350) as $btcf)
            {
            $bh = $btcf->health;                
            echo "<tr>    
             <td>$btcf->name</td>
             <td><span class='btn btn-xs btn-success'>$btcf->reward</span></td>
             <td><span class='btn btn-xs btn-info'><i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i> $btcf->timer_in_minutes</span></td>
             <td><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-bitcoin'>$btcf->paid_week</span></td> 
             <td>$btcf->active_users</td>
            }
        }
?>
```

If you help to solve this problem, then I can learn something new with that. If any other information is needed, I can update it.

Comment: Could you dump $obj variable like this? `var_dump($obj);` Just to see what was returned. Also did you checked that $json returned something?

Comment: Currently site API is not working but if it work I will update it. Is this will help http://www.takepure.info/list.php or not

Comment: API is live now. Now you can see var_dump($gg); from above link. I hope this will help me to get more accurate answer.

Comment: As you can see, api returned array of objects. What information do you want to gather?

Comment: I have just edit my above code, you can find there what i want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appearing of `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object` means that `json_decode($json);` didn't return expected object and there was error.

To check it you can use something like this

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    // handle json error. 
    $errorMessage = json_last_error_msg();
    echo $errorMessage;
    // or 
    // throw new Exception($errorMessage);
}
```

Docs:

[json_last_error_msg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php)

[json_last_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)

Comment: I will use it soon if the site api work properly but sorry to say that, where I have to add this.

Comment: Can you tell me what would happen after adding this code and json_decode($json); didn't return expected object

Comment: How to handle this kind of errors is up to you, it depends. Maybe you can just show "sorry, service unavailable" to your end users, or you can retry request to API.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead of last `<?php` block:

```
<?php
foreach($obj as $company) {
   echo $company->name.'<br>';
   echo $company->reward.'<br>';
   echo $company->timer_in_minutes.'<br>';
   echo $company->paid_week.'<br>';
   echo $company->active_users.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: But I am getting error on at thispoint $gg = $obj->list_data->premium->BTC; then why I have to edit inside foreach

Comment: Ok, I mean that `$obj` is array of objects, therefore you are unable to access it like object `$obj->list_data`

Comment: Then why sometime it works and sometime not. This is without your code.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I just read [documentation](https://faucethub.io/api) One possible reason could be, that api is returning some error. For example `{"status":402,"message":"This faucet has insufficient funds to send the payout."}` You could try to throw some exception if you didn't get desired result. And therfore you can't get data from response.